# Handle a HicariCP Oracle connection attempts

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, hikaricp

I presume i have a close to default HicariConfiguration with MaximumPoolSize(5).
The problem i faced with is there're a lot of attempts to connect to database even the first one failed. I mean, for instance, the password i'm going to use to connect to Oracle is wrong and connection fails, but then we have one more attempts to connect to database which lock the account as a result.

Question: What HicariCP setting is supposed to be used to limit up to 1 number of attempt to connect?

Thanks for any information!

### UPDATE

env.conf:

```
jdbc {
   test1 {
       datasourceClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
       dataSourceUrl=.....jdbc url
       dataSourceUser=USER
       dataSourcePassword=password
       setMaximumPoolSize = 5
       setJdbc4ConnectionTest = true
         }
}
```

Conf file is read by means of ConfigFactory, and create HicariConfig based on conf file (setDriverClassName etc).
Output of HikariConfig:

```
autoCommit.....................true
connectionTimeOut..............30000
idleTimeOut....................600000
initializationFailFast.........false
isolateInternalQueries.........false
jdbc4ConnectionTest............test
maxLifetime....................1800000
minimumIdle....................5
```

Comment: Are you sure that your application does not do reconnection?

Comment: Definitely, yes, it does not. There is a single simple function is to connect to database, execute query and work further with ResultSet.

Comment: hm, can you provide your HicariCP configuration?

Comment: Updated description with configuration details

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/312, As explained at the end of this issue, HikariCP will keep trying to acquire a connection. It removed the acquireRetries parameters deliberately.  so the way is to configure the right username/password, since DB only lock after authenticaions failures.

Here's extracted from the issue. HikariCP intends to retry forever.

> Back to acquireRetries... Without a concept of acquireRetries, how
>   long does the dedicated thread continue to try to create a new
>   connection? **Forever**. The background creation thread will continue to
>   try to add a connection to the pool forever, or until one of three
>   conditions is met:

Comment: I do not handle the password and of course it can be expired/changed and I should live with it. The problem is that my default configuration lead to making ~ 20 attempts to connect, this number is a matching number of "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28000: the account is locked"

Comment: Yes, but the attempts was configured by acquireRetries, and looks HikariCP does'n consider it is a reason to support.  so you can either follow HikariCP's philosophy or switch to C3P0. connection pool.

Comment: c3p0 properties :
acquireRetryAttempts
acquireRetryDelay
breakAfterAcquireFailure